# Bootstrap active class dynamic navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am loading nav bar from a HTML file using the `load()` method. I want the active class for each `<li>` to change dynamically. I tried many options, but it is not working.

Here is the nav bar code which I saved as `navigation.html`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Theatre Count</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-left" id="nav">
      <li><a href="home.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>&nbsp;Home</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="status.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>&nbsp;Status</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span>&nbsp;Live Images</a></li>
      <li><a href="reports.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span>&nbsp;Reports</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span>&nbsp;Archive</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp;Log Out</button>
</nav>
```

Here is my `status.html` page code:

```
<body>    
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#navigation').load('navigation.html');
    });
  </script> 
  <script> 
    $("#nav li a").on("click", function(){    
        $("#nav li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any previously "active" li
        $(this).closest("li").addClass("active"); //Set click li as active
    });         
  </script>    
  <div id="navigation"></div>
</body>
```

Here my active class script is not working.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d2sxmn1L/1 it's working

Comment: there it is working.but it is not working for me.when i click report it goes to report.html page but still the status is active

Answer (score 0):

Please see the example below. hope it useful for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
       //Click on any li in ul with class 'navbar-nav'
      $('ul.navbar-nav li').click(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this); // declare variable for current li that we click
        $('ul.navbar-nav').find('li.active').last().removeClass('active') //find all li that class class active and remove
        $this.addClass('active'); //add 'active' class to current li.
      });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick, easy and short piece of jquery code that works well for this requirement.

```
// Sets active link in Bootstrap menu
// Add this code in a central place used\shared by all pages
// like your _Layout.cshtml in ASP.NET MVC for example
$('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parents('li,ul').addClass('active');
```

Credits:
https://www.codementor.io/tips/2948713286/how-to-set-active-class-to-nav-menu-from-twitter-bootstrap